# Need tips on best way to set up my web applicaiton to use different settings based on it's environment

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am finishing up an asp.net 4 (MVC 3) web app and for the time being I have hard coded in things like the data source connection strings and payment gateway service references.

What I would like to do is have the app code detect what environment it is running in like test or production and use the appropriate settings based on that.

I must also add that I have a service reference created in VS 2010 as well that points to some sand boxed web services used during dev and testing. I am also not sure on how to tell my app which one to use based on it's current environment. Should I create a reference for both production and test web services?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx

Comment: John... your link seems to provide what I need, post it as an answer and I'll give you credit for your help. Thanks